# AccessDeniedHttpException when visiting Drupal 8 website after a disaster recovery

Tags: symfony, drupal-8, access-denied

I have got this error message when visiting Drupal 8 website after a disaster recovery:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again
>   later.Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException:
>   in Drupal\Core\Routing\AccessAwareRouter->checkAccess()
>   (line 114 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/AccessAwareRouter.php).
>
> Drupal\Core\Routing\AccessAwareRouter->matchRequest(Object)
>   (Line: 101)
>       Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(Object,
>   'kernel.request', Object) (Line: 108)
>       Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request',
>   Object) (Line: 129)
>       Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
>       Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
>       Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
>       Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 184)
>       Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->fetch(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 121)
>       Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->lookup(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 75)
>       Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
>       Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object,
>   1, 1) (Line: 50)
>       Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object,
>   1, 1) (Line: 23)
>       Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 664)
>       Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 18)

By looking at the `core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/AccessAwareRouter.php`, and reading up Drupal's and Symfony's documentation, it's pointing to the direction where it might be something wrong with the current user's authentification. What are the next steps I should do to find the root cause of the problem?

Comment: Did you get a resolution to this problem?